# I want to make if else in php but i don't know how

Tags: php

I want to make if else using 'score'. But i don't know how to code that, 
for example if `score = 10` you will pass the test, and if `score = 7` you will not pass the test.

I have trying for 4 days, but I haven't find the solution, I hope someone can help me.

```
  <?php session_start(); ?>
<?php include 'database.php'; ?>
<?php

    //Check to see if score is set_error_handler

    if(!isset($_SESSION['score'])) {
        $_SESSION['score'] = 0;
    }

    if($_POST) {
        $number  = $_POST['number'];
        $selected_choice = $_POST['choice'];
        $next = $number+1;

        /*
        *   Get total questions
        */
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `questions_tak`";

        //Get result

        $results = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
        $total = $results->num_rows;


        /*
        *   Get correct choice
        */

        $query = "SELECT * FROM `choices_tak`
                    WHERE question_number = $number AND is_correct = 1";

        //Get result

        $result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

        //Get row

        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

        //Set correct choice

        $correct_choice = $row['id'];

        //Compare
        if($correct_choice == $selected_choice) {
            //Answer is correct
            $_SESSION['score']++;
        }


        //Check if last question
        if($number == $total) {
            header("Location: final.php");
            exit();
        } else {
            header("Location: question.php?n=".$next);
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: It seems like you're already using `if/else` in your code? What don't you understand about it? An example attempt at the code you're trying to make would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   <?php
//If you have a score variable
$score=0; //Your value
//If Score 10 or greater than 10 
if($score>=10){
echo "Passed";
}else{ 
echo "Failed"; //If score less than 10
}
?>
```

For more details visit https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_if_else.asp